# Unity C# не получается отправить Raycast по середине (уходит влево)?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Raycast уходит влево. Как его сделать по середине?
Код:

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Vector2.down, Vector2.up);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вторая переменная у raycast - это вектор направления луча. Если необходимо направить его вправо, то используйте Vector2.right или Vector2(1, 0). В вашем примере луч направлен вверх.

Answer (score 0):

давно имел дело с этим, но мне кажется что вопрос в том где именно генерится луч. Потому что если он генерится внутри какого-то обьекта - то он может быть направлен в некую сторону относительно локальной системы координат обьекта. Это значит что при направлении строго вверх ты можешь получить абсолютно любое направление в мировой системе координат.